# Calling stored procedure on i Series using IBM DB2 Connect driver

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange, rpgle, db2-connect

I have a C# application, from where I am trying to call an ISeries Stored Procedure (wrapping an RPGLE program). This RPGLE program returns a result set back to my C# application.
When I try to call the stored procedure, it errors and hangs indefinitely. In the debug mode, I can see the SQL error message as shown at the end of the post. If I use OleDBConnection it works fine, but it doesn't work with DB2 Connect.

I have tried to setup Tracing on my page, but it didn't help as the page just hangs and I am not able to view the stack trace.

On ISeries side, I can see that the program executes correctly (For testing, I am writing a record in a test file at the end of the program.)

Has anybody else faced this error before? I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

**Code:-**

```
DB2Connection conn1 = new DB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings  ["db2IBM"].ConnectionString);
        conn1.Open();

        string callString5 = "PGMLIBLE.GETCONSIGNMENTS";

        DB2Command cmd1 = new DB2Command(callString5, conn1);
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.CommandTimeout = 5;

        DB2Parameter prmCons = cmd1.Parameters.Add("prmCons", DB2Type.Char, 7);
        prmCons.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        prmCons.Value = "JUT0016";

        DB2Parameter prmCmp = cmd1.Parameters.Add("prmCmp", DB2Type.Char, 3);
        prmCmp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        prmCmp.Value = "DTA";

        DB2Parameter prmIorE = cmd1.Parameters.Add("prmIorE", DB2Type.Char, 1);
        prmIorE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        prmIorE.Value = "Y";

        DB2DataAdapter adp = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        adp.Fill(dt);
     // If I just execute cmd1.executeNonquery it doesn't error.
     //  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();

        conn1.Close();
        conn1.Dispose();
        cmd1.Dispose();
```

**Error Message:-**

```
ERROR [58005] [IBM][DB2.NET] SQL0902 An unexpected exception has occurred in  Process: 5652 Thread 10 AppDomain: Name:aa196883-1-129406018469512609
There are no context policies.

Function: SQLExecDirectADONET (Params)
 CallStack:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.HandleUnknownErrors(String strFncMsg, Exception exception, Boolean bThrow)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Command.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, DB2CursorType reqCursorType, Boolean abortOnOptValueChg, Boolean skipDeleted, Boolean isResultSet, Int32 maxRows, Boolean skipInitialValidation)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Command.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Command.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at ShowConsignmentsOpen.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\TestStoredProc\ShowConsignmentsOpen.aspx.cs:line 50
   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.showconsignmentsopen_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\teststoredproc\f35f719b\99c08192\App_Web_yti93vc5.2.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Connection conn) InnerException Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. Check InnerException property for more detail.  SQLSTATE=58005
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always done the following:

```
    DB2Connection conn1 = new DB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["db2IBM"].ConnectionString);
    conn1.Open();

    string callString5 = "PGMLIBLE.GETCONSIGNMENTS";

    DB2Command cmd1 = new DB2Command(callString5, conn1);
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.CommandTimeout = 5;

    cmd1.Parameters.Add("prmCons", DB2Type.Char, 7).Value = "JUT0016";
    prmCons.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    cmd1.Parameters.Add("prmCmp", DB2Type.Char, 3).Value = "DTA";
    prmCmp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    cmd1.Parameters.Add("prmIorE", DB2Type.Char, 1).Value = "Y";
    prmIorE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    DB2DataAdapter adp = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    adp.Fill(dt);
 // If I just execute cmd1.executeNonquery it doesn't error.
 //  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();

    conn1.Close();
    conn1.Dispose();
    cmd1.Dispose();
```

I can't remember how to do the direction, but this is basically how I have implemented this in the past.

Comment: HI Mike, This is teh same as the way I am doing it. The code works fine with Oledb driver, so I doubt that the code has a problem. The error message says that "There are no context policies." Can it be because of some authority issue I have on my machine or if there is some settings that I have missed during my DB2 installation?

Comment: I know the IBM iSeries .NET drivers can be picky. In a strange error like this it might not hurt to try. Especially if it works in OLEDB. Sorry, I don't have any others suggestions beyond triple checking your authorities.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked long ago, but I'll answer it anyway.

Take a look at this error message:

> ERROR [58005] [IBM][DB2.NET] SQL0902 An unexpected exception has occurred in  Process: 5652 Thread 10 AppDomain: Name:aa196883-1-129406018469512609
>   There are no context policies.

After doing a search on the text *"There are no context policies."*, I found this:

[MSDN AppDomain.ToString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc99ft2.aspx)

There, you will see the following:

> **Return Value**
>   Type: [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)
>   A string formed by concatenating the literal string "Name:", the friendly name of the application domain, and either string representations of the context policies or the string "There are no context policies."

### So, what does this mean?

Most likely, it comes from this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings  ["db2IBM"].ConnectionString
```

That is exactly how you wrote it.

That error could be caused by either of these:

1. those spaces are causing the error, or
2. `db2IBM` does not exist in your Web.config file's Connection String section.

For help with setting up your Connection String section, see the following:

[Setting up connection string in ASP.NET to SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5642474/153923)