# ASP.NET Web API - clean architecture - appsettings.json in service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, clean-architecture

I have an ASP.NET web application with clean architecture:

- Application
- Domain
- Infrastructure

In the main API project, I have an `appsettings.json` with URL to anm external API :

```
{
    "ExternalAPI": {
        "API": "url",
        "Secret": "xxxx"
    }
}
```

In the `Application`, I have multiple services, and some of them need to use this external URL for the API with a secret key.

The problem is I don't know how to get this url from `appsetting.json`.

Comment: Please refer :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880443/creating-a-string-in-a-web-config-and-use-it-in-a-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880443/creating-a-string-in-a-web-config-and-use-it-in-a-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Core, you would typically manage configuration values in the appsettings.json file and access them through the IConfiguration interface. Here's how you can create a setting in your appsettings.json and access it in an ASP.NET Core Web API:

Add the Setting to appsettings.json:

**#Open the appsettings.json file in your ASP.NET Core project and add
a setting like this:**

```
{
  "ExternalAPI": {
    "API": "url",
    "Secret": "xxxx"
  },
  // ... other settings ...
}
```

**Access the Setting in Code:**

In your ASP.NET Core Web API application, you can access these settings using the IConfiguration interface. Here's an example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet("external-api")]
    public IActionResult GetExternalApiSettings()
    {
        var apiUrl = _configuration["ExternalAPI:API"];
        var secret = _configuration["ExternalAPI:Secret"];

        if (apiUrl != null && secret != null)
        {
            return Ok(new { API = apiUrl, Secret = secret });
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the GetExternalApiSettings action method retrieves the values of "API" and "Secret" from the appsettings.json configuration using the IConfiguration instance.

**Register IConfiguration in Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other services registration ...

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

If you're using ASP.NET Framework (not ASP.NET Core), you can still access settings stored in the web.config file. Here's how to create a setting in web.config and access it in your ASP.NET Framework Web API:

**Add the Setting to web.config:**
Open the web.config file in your ASP.NET Framework project, typically located in the root directory. Add an  section to store your setting:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... other configuration settings ... -->
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ExternalAPI.API" value="url" />
        <add key="ExternalAPI.Secret" value="xxxx" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Access the Setting in Code:**
In your ASP.NET Framework Web API application, you can access these settings using the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;

public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetExternalApiSettings()
    {
        string apiUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExternalAPI.API"];
        string secret = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExternalAPI.Secret"];

        if (apiUrl != null && secret != null)
        {
            return Ok(new { API = apiUrl, Secret = secret });
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

For more : [Reading config from appSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/read-app-settings)

Comment: I'm using ASP .NET 7, the main problem is i am using Factory pattern so i have controller where i have one factory service with provider which gives me access to other 10 services depends on settings in the method parameter.

By this i need to add configuration to my class factory and to all my services in constructor which i dont want to do.