# Connect To Sql server which is in other domain from WinForms using Windows Authentication Mode

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created WinForm App and want to connect To Sql server using Windows Authentication Mode. But Sql Server is in other domain and WinForm App is in other domain.

I am not able to connect. Tell me how to do this ?

**Edit**

These two systems are in same LAN but in different groups....Do i need to go through Active Directory concepts if Yes then from where i should start.

Comment: **bold** should generally be used sparingly, for emphasis. If the *majority* of your question is in bold, it comes across more as shouting.

Comment: checkout my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104962/sql-server-error-provider-sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-s

Comment: Is this totally seperate domains or do the two domains trust each other?

Comment: they don't trust each other

Comment: I think you'd need the credentials of a user on the remote domain.

Comment: These two systems are in same LAN but in different groups....Do i need to go through Active Directory concepts.

Comment: This seems such an odd thing to be trying to do, as you state, there are two separated domains on one LAN, and i can only imagine that this was done for a reason, security purposes. If neither domain can communicate with each other then your answer is right there.

Comment: Use SQL authentication.