# Remote Connection Error in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis-8

I am trying to make a registration page, that stores Username, password,and email, 
but
When ever i try to Connect database using this string,

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
 conn.Open();
```

Following Error appears:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I searched everywhere, but it didn't helped me..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The issue starts from `web.config` and the connection string that is located at `RConnectionString` according to the code line you give.

Locate this string and fix it to been able to connect to your database.

And some examples here: [Setting up connection string in ASP.NET to SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/setting-up-connection-string-in-asp-net-to-sql-server)