# Asp.net Entity FrameWork No connection string found

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, connection-string

I have a two project, one asp.net MVC project and second .net library project with entity framework 6.0
I just added reference of last project to the main MVC project and trying to use class OnlineShopEntities extended DBContext

```
OnlineShopEntities db = new OnlineShopEntities();
bool exists = db.User.Any(i => i.Username == username);
```

I have a error when using

```
No connection string named 'OnlineShopEntities' could be found in the application config file.
```

How can I add manually connection string in web.config file and how can I write it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up connection string in ASP.NET to SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/setting-up-connection-string-in-asp-net-to-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the `app.config` file for the project that contains your Entity Framework code. It likely contains the connection string you need to place in your MVC project's `web.config`.

Comment: From the description of the problem in the question, this is almost certainly the answer