# passwords for web.config in development and production

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

The audit department does not want the programmers to have access to the production sql account for the web apps.

Right now the programmers know the username and password and its being entered in the web.config.

Is there a way where the web.config can be configured to allow the programmers to do their job? Once the web app is moved to production its using different credentials where the programmers dont know the password.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can use a different web config in each environment.  I'm not quite sure on the details of how to implement it, but I do know this is what my place of employment implements, for the exact same reasons you are describing

Comment: use this kind of setup http://stackoverflow.com/a/5642578/159270  you do not give there any password