# How to solve "Login failed for user 'domain\Username'" in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have a website where I need to fetch data from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. But I'm getting an error

> Login failed for user 'domain\Username'

I googled for it then I get that to change property of SQL Server -> Properties -> Security -> Server authentication to SQL Server and Windows authentication mode only I'm still getting the same error. I don't want to use ID and password in connection string

My connection string:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Please help me.

Comment: Since your question is product-specific you are more likely to get help if you add the appropriate tag (naming the product) to the question.

Comment: @ErwinSmout- no , actually I had host my website on IIS 8 ( localhost). I can fetch data properly if I run code from Visual studio. But it getting error when I try to run from IIS

Comment: You got error on IIS because IIS have it own user which will load website. There for you will need add this user to your sql server or to use normal userId/password authentication.

Comment: Is there any other solution, I dont want to use ID, password. my username is already added in server

Comment: @d0812 Can you connect your database with SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @SankarRaj- Yes I can connect database with sql without any ID password. with servername as server name and authentication as windows authentication.

Comment: @d0812 what kind of authentication in IIS you use? Anonymous or Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

add user id and passsword

or

1) Go to Server Explorer tab on VS

2) In Data Connections right click (click on properties) on your db

3) copy Connection String

Comment: Yes I use the same connectionstring  in web.confog file. But no use

Comment: what is your Data Source localhost or server

Comment: @ khan its servername

Comment: are you able to access your db in SSMS

Comment: @ Khan- Yes I can access the server

Comment: [Setting up connection string in ASP.NET to SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/setting-up-connection-string-in-asp-net-to-sql-server)

Comment: just tel me- my username added in server, thats why I can connect with it by vs. so in ID password what I needed to add. I use windows authentication instede of sql authentication while connect to SSMS. so is this error?

Comment: use `Integrated Security=SSPI`