# Connection Strings in Web Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

I am needing to pass username and password so that any user can run stored procedures on a database.  In my web config I have my code set to this

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Connection1" value="server=validserver;database=validdatabase;uID=validuserid;password=validpassword;" />
</appSettings>
```

And in my C# - I first set a variable equal to the connection like so:

```
public const string MainDBConn = "Connection1";
```

and any time I want to use this connection string I call it like this

```
RunSQLQuery(MainDBCon, "nameofstoredprocedure");
```

However I keep getting this error thrown, which to me says it is an invalid conenction string, but my server name, database, userid and password are all valid...

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

What do I alter so that I can use this connection string in my syntax to connect to my server instance?

**EDIT**
Altering my connection string to be

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection1"].ConnectionString;
```

Now produces an error of:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
>     The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>     (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**EDIT 2**
I modified my webconfig connection as suggested by @Khazratbek in his answer and now I get this error:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.
>   This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.
>   The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=3672; handshake=0;

That is strange to me as I have my timeout set to 0, which if I understand properly should set this to be non timeout

```
CommandTimeout = 0;
```

Comment: string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection1"].ConnectionString;

Comment: I believe you are just passing MainDBConn string constant to build the connection, not the actual connection string, which is why you are getting error.

Comment: try to check if SQL server service is running? this error is because of SQL services is not running or your server name is not true

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/setting-up-connection-string-in-asp-net-to-sql-server

Comment: @Smart - services is running on the computer/server I want to connect to.  I can connect to SSMS on the server with the credentials I am trying to pass.

Comment: are you using Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Connection string in web.config usually like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add 
name="connectionStringName" 
connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
Catalog=yourDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User 
ID=userName;Password=password"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

and then read connection like:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Follow the following steps to connect to SQL server:

1-  Click Server Explorer in visual studio and then click it, add connection will display.

2-  Enter your Server name and password and the click ok.

3- Go to properties and copy connection string.

4- paste copied connection string here

```
connectionString="copied connection string"
```

[image][image]

Comment: I tried your above syntax, see my edit that I get now.

Comment: go to start > all programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tool > and the click SQL Server Configuration Manager. And then run SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)

Comment: following your updated solution, I still get the error from my Edit 2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the *web.config* you have to add not *appSettings*, and the next one:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Connection1" connectionString="Server=validserver;uid=validuserid;pwd=validpassword;database=validdatabase"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then in your page:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

And your connection string will be:

```
string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection1"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Where does connectionstrings belong? (what's the parent)

Comment: @RuneJeppesen *configuration* tag