# Invalid connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Apparently this connection string is incorrect? 
    connectionString="Server=mydb.com:1433/sqlExpress;Database=d;User Id=d;Password=pw;"

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/) could be helpful.

Comment: I think you can provide some details in your question. Like the method you're using to connect. Are you sure the problem is in the `connectionstring`?. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: The documentation around this stuff is as clear as it can possibly be.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. The server was not found or is not accessible. So the first thing you should check is whether the server exists **as you named it in the connection string**. I will guarantee that it does not, and I don't even have to look at your environment to make that statement. The link that DCruz22 provided actually solves your problem if you read it closely enough, especially this part https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connection-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: @CraigW. he is actually specifying the port incorrectly. it's a comma not a colon.

Answer (score 3):

the first think that I see is that you have type wrong this part

```
Server=mydb.com:1433
```

use

```
Server=mydb.com,1433
```

the sql server use the comma to separate the port.

Also take a look at that answer: [Setting up connection string in ASP.NET to SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/setting-up-connection-string-in-asp-net-to-sql-server/5642578#5642578)