# how to handle "argumentexception was unhandled by user" error in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = @"ADMIN\LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=maha;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into dbo.student Values ('" + TB1.Text + "','" + TB2.Text + "','" + TB3.Text + "','" + @rm + "')", con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is wrong on `ADMIN\LOCALHOST` and from there come the error message.

Must be like:

```
 con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=maha;Integrated Security=True";
```

Beside that you must [parameterize your query](https://www.google.com/search?q=parameterized+queries&rls=com.microsoft:%2A&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1)  , to avoid sql injection https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection

[How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

and also you can read: 
[Setting up connection string in ASP.NET to SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/setting-up-connection-string-in-asp-net-to-sql-server/5642578#5642578)