# how do I use a connecting string variable defined in a file reuse in another file in same C# project?

Tags: c#

I've a `databaseconnectionString` variable  in file databasetablename.cs and I want to use this `databaseconnectionString` in my other files without creating the connection string details for each api,following is how my project structure looks like and how I tried to use the variable `databaseconnectionString` which throws an error `doesnot exist in current context` ,what am I missing?how to use the `databaseconnectionString` in product.cs file?

```
Repository
   --->BuildRepositoryfolder
       Product.cs
   --->DatabaseConnections
       databasetablename.cs


databasetablename.cs

    public class databasetablename
    {
        public string databaseconnectionString = "server=xx.xx.xxx.xxx;database=aci_dev;uid=wciadmin;pwd=adSHEEP91min;";
    }

Product.cs
      public IEnumerable<Info> InfoSearch(LookaheadRunsFilterCriteria filterCriteria)
       {  
            var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = databaseconnectionString; --> throws an error

       }
```

Comment: The convention is to put connection strings in your app.config or web.config file. Is this an ASP.NET project? WPF? UWP? WinForm?

Comment: ya,this is ASP.net..what exactly should I put?can you provide an example?

Comment: Look at [Setting up connection string in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642474/). The same code works on databases other than SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that's what you want:

```
conn.ConnectionString = databasetable.databaseconnectionString;
```

Comment: this says databasetable does nto exist in current context

Comment: add using databasetable;

Comment: I added but `databasetablename.` doesnt pop up databaseconnectionString

Comment: you need to set the variable public

Comment: it is public as you can see in my question

Comment: try to make it static, i don't see your full code ^^

Comment: depends on how you structure your program, depeding on the way you do it, sometimes you need to set a variable static to see it ^^ mark my answer if i solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

In C#, to use a variable defined in one class from another there are several requirements.  If `DatabaseTable` is a class with a variable `ConnectionString` that you want to use inside another class `Program`, then:

1. The two classes must be in the same assembly/project and `ConnectionString` must be marked `public` or `internal` -- OR -- `ConnectionString` must be marked `public` and `DatabaseTable` must be marked `public` and the project with `Program` must reference the project with `DatabaseTable`.

In one project:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var str = DatabaseTable.ConnectionString;
    }
}

class DatabaseTable {
    internal static string ConnectionString = "test";
}
```

In separate projects:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var str = DatabaseTable.ConnectionString;
    }
}

public class DatabaseTable {
    public static string ConnectionString = "test";
}
```

[Access modifiers (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

---

2. If you want `ConnectionString` to be available to `Program` by just referencing the `DatabaseTable` class, without creating an instance of that class, then `ConnectionString` must be marked `static` or `const`.

With instances:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var table = new DatabaseTable();
        var str = table.ConnectionString;
    }
}

public class DatabaseTable {
    public string ConnectionString = "test";
}
```

With `static`:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var str = DatabaseTable.ConnectionString;
    }
}

public class DatabaseTable {
    public static string ConnectionString = "test";
}
```

[`const` (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)

[`static` (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Comment: Namespaces could also be an issue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may also try singleton pattern. I will give You example I have in my project already. I am using `OleDbConnection`, but You may adjust it for Your purpose ( `MySqlConnection` ). You will have to connect only once. Your methods related to database could be also inside Broker.cs . Later, for example inside form, when needed, You will be using `Broker.dajBrokera().methodName()`. You will have to add `using namespace (name)` too. Note private constructor, and dajBrokera() which will create only one instance of Broker class.

```
public class Broker
{
  OleDbConnection konekcija;

  OleDbCommand komanda;

  void konektujSe()
  {
        konekcija = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\...;Persist Security Info=False;");
        komanda = konekcija.CreateCommand();
  }

  private static Broker broker;

  public static Broker dajBrokera()
  {
      if (broker == null)
      {
          broker = new Broker();
      }
      return broker;
  }

  private Broker()
  {
      konektujSe();
  }
}
```

Hope this can help. Sorry for using OleDbConnection, instead MySqlConnection.It would take me more time to answer, and I suppose faster answer could be more helpful.
Best regards.